# How to achieve Live Streaming of videos in iOS (iPhone/iPad) using Kaltura?

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, kaltura

i m able to play Live Streaming Video in iOS using following code :

```
NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];

MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];

mp.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[mp setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
//[mp setFullscreen:YES];

[self.view addSubview:[mp view]];

[mp prepareToPlay];
[mp play];
```

what i m passing is .m3u8 file format url to the MPMoviePlayerController, and i m able to play Live Streaming. but how can i achieve it using Kaltura's Live Streaming ?

according to http://corp.kaltura.com/company/news/press-release/kaltura-%E2%80%98cracks-code%E2%80%99-reliable-hls-video-streaming-android-devices there is Android SDK for live streaming of videos using Kaltura, is there any iOS Kaltura SDK for Live Streaming ? or Do i have to use iOS built in MPMoviePlayerController for Live Streaming , if yes then what is the way ?

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to play Kaltura live streaming you just need to grab the manifest url with the following params:
/format/applehttp/protocol/http/a.m3u8

more details here:
http://knowledge.kaltura.com/faq/how-retrieve-download-or-streaming-url-using-api-calls

Comment: one more thing , should i use MPMoviePlayerController to play live stream or Kaltura's player ? if Kaltura's player then what is the way ? Will there be options to switch between Video Quality ? like 360p , 264p as YouTube player provides.

Comment: First of all MPMoviePlayer is deprecated on iOS9 so i suggest you wont use it. You can use the AV Foundation in order to get access to the media stack and choose the playback bitrate